# All domain users have full control

Tags: permissions, security, active-directory

On our SharePoint 2010 development server, I noticed that all domain users had full control. On the "Intranet Owners" group, which has Full Control permission level, there are the admin accounts from the AD, but there's also the account `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users`. Could this be what's allowing everyone on the AD to have full control? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google said "Granting permissions to all authenticated users grants access to all members of your domain, which could include vendors, partners, and people from other companies." :)